# Accents not properly reported in MySQL dump

Tags: mysql, debian, dump, arch-linux

I'm using MySQL 5.1.58 on Debian Sqeeze and I'm trying to restore the dump of a database. Once it is restored I noticed that all the accented chars had become other chars as Ã¹ or Ã¨: completely different.

Looking in the dump I've seen that the problem is not at importing, but at exporting, becouse the strange chars were in the dump.

I exported that dump from another installation of MySQL (5.5) on ArchLinux. I tried also to use the argument --default-character-set=8tf8 in mysqldump, but it did not work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue with `mysqldump`.  Instead of using `utf8` as the default encoding, use `latin1`.  Also, you can use `-N` (which will specify `SET NAMES`) so that the encoded text will not be re-encoded by mysql.  I.e.:

```
mysqldump -u username -p --default-character-set=latin1 -N database > backup.sql
mysql -u username -p --default-character-set=latin1 database < backup.sql
```

([source](http://docforge.com/wiki/Mysqldump))